# Powershell won't preserve the type cast when updating an object's property

Tags: .net, powershell

I have an array of objects I want to sort on their "Device" property. The challenge is that the "Device" property can be an IP or a hostname. So, my approach was to separate them into an array with IPs and another by name (strings).

The problem is that when I cast the Device column to a Net.IPAddress and save it back it reverts to a string.

here is what I am doing:

```
$DeviceByIP = @()
$DeviceByHostname = @()
foreach ($row in $data) {
    try {
        [Net.IPAddress]$row.Device = $row.Device
        $DeviceByIP += $row
    } catch {
        #[string]$row.Device | out-null
        $DeviceByHostname += $row
    }
}
```

When I do this: `[Net.IPAddress]$row.Device = $row.Device` it reverts back to a string. So if I do this:
$DeviceByIP | %{$_.Device.GetType().fullname}

I see the Device property of the objects are all System.String.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is $row.device a string or a Net.IPAddress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't mention what type of object $row is, but it appears that $row is a native .NET object with Device exposed as a System.String.  If you don't have access to the source code of the $row type, you can use Select-Object to replace each $row object with a PSCustomType object that has the same properties:

```
$DeviceByIP = @()
$DeviceByHostname = @()
foreach ($row in $data) {
    try {
        $row = $row | Select-Object *
        [Net.IPAddress]$row.Device = $row.Device
        $DeviceByIP += $row
    } catch {
        $DeviceByHostname += $row
    }
}
```

And if you didn't want to rely on exception handling, which is a little bit costlier, you could use the TryParse method of System.Net.IPAddress:

```
$DeviceByIP = @()
$DeviceByHostname = @()
$ipAddress = $null
foreach ($row in $data) {
    $row = $row | Select-Object *
    if ([Net.IPAddress]::TryParse($row.Device, [ref]$ipAddress)) {
        $row.Device = $ipAddress
        $DeviceByIP += $row
    } else {
        $DeviceByHostname += $row
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't you want to do:

```
$DeviceByIP += [Net.IPAddress]$row.Device
```

I'm guessing the column type is a string, so changing individual rows probably won't fly...

Answer (score 0):

BTW *if* the ip address is of type [Net.IPAddress] and not just a string with an ip address in it, you don't have to rely on InvalidCastExceptions.  You can check types like so:

```
if ($row.Device -is [Net.IPAddress]) {
   $DeviceByIP += $row.Device
}
else if ($row.Device -is [string]) {
   $DeviceByHostname += row.Device
}
else { Write-Error "Oops" }
```